# Formatted output with number of occurrences on specific fields

Tags: shell, unix, awk

How can I format the output as follow into the desired format:

```
SUBPATH                     DANAME               DMNAME       GROUP        STATE
cciss/c0d0                  cciss/c0d0           -            -            ENABLED
sda                         xiv0_001b            emc000       gicn2db_PRD  ENABLED
sdb                         xiv0_001b            emc000       gicn2db_PRD  ENABLED
sdd                         xiv0_001b            emc000       gicn2db_PRD  ENABLED
sdc                         xiv0_001b            emc000       gicn2db_PRD  ENABLED
sdx                         xiv0_004f            0000         ddrr2db_PRD  ENABLED
sdad                        xiv0_004f            0000         ddrr2db_PRD  DISABLED
sdaa                        xiv0_004f            0000         ddrr2db_PRD  ENABLED
sdu                         xiv0_004f            0000         ddrr2db_PRD  ENABLED
sdaj                        xiv0_005d            0001         gconfdb_PRD  DISABLED
sdag                        xiv0_005d            0001         gconfdb_PRD  ENABLED
sdah                        xiv0_005d            0001         gconfdb_PRD  ENABLED
...
```

For example I need to parse this block and create an output as follow:

```
xiv0_001b has <total_amount> of ENABLED paths and <total_amount> of DISABLED paths.
...
```

Because each name is being repeated few times (status and disk name...)

Preferably using `awk` to avoid multiple parsings using `grep` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{$5=="ENABLED"?e[$2]++:d[$2]++}END{for(i in e)printf "%s ENABLED %d DISABLED %d\n",i,e[i],d[i]}' file
xiv0_005d ENABLED 2 DISABLED 1
xiv0_004f ENABLED 3 DISABLED 1
cciss/c0d0 ENABLED 1 DISABLED 0
xiv0_001b ENABLED 4 DISABLED 0
```

Modify the `printf` format as you need.

Comment: nice one. add all disks are disabled part would be perfect. e.g. `$2` not in `e`, only in `d`

Comment: @Kent yes this logic could easily be implemented in the `END` block if the OP wanted.